# Performance facts between Fluent Validation and Data Annotation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, fluentvalidation

Does somebody have performance experience either real measures between Fluent Validation and Data Annotation ? Does ASP MVC 5 has great improves about that ?

Comment: Probably imperceptible. I imagine they both use caching for high performance. Choose the one that makes the most sense to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807472/fluent-validation-vs-data-annotations

Comment: ASP.NET MVC 3 doesn't implement caching, at least a good caching of metadata and from validators.