# How to manually validate a model with attributes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a class called `User` and a property `Name`

```
public class User
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to validate it, and if there are any errors add to the controller's `ModelState` or instantiate another modelstate...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewUser(UserViewModel userVM)
{
    User u = new User();
    u.Name = null;

    /* something */

    // assume userVM is valid
    // I want the following to be false because `user.Name` is null
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        TempData["NewUserCreated"] = "New user created sucessfully";

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View();
}
```

The attributes works for `UserViewModel`, but I want to know how to validate a class without posting it to an action.

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You can use [Validator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.tryvalidateobject#System_ComponentModel_DataAnnotations_Validator_TryValidateObject_System_Object_System_ComponentModel_DataAnnotations_ValidationContext_System_Collections_Generic_ICollection_System_ComponentModel_DataAnnotations_ValidationResult__System_Boolean_) to accomplish this.

```
var context = new ValidationContext(u, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();

bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(u, context, validationResults, true);
```

Comment: A doubt: why don't directly use the  `System.Web.Mvc.Controller.TryValidateModel(u)` method?

Comment: @GianpieroCaretti because that gives unneeded references? This is most likely used in console applications or libraries most of the time. There is little to no need for this in normal situations when it comes down to a web application.

Comment: @Viezevingertjes: I do agree.

Comment: Don't know what 'gives unneeded references' mean in This using context. Can someone explain please? Is [TryValidateModel] right there in controller and we create instance of object in that controller too?

Comment: If we are validating within a controller, then Yes, we can use `System.Web.Mvc.Controller.TryValidateModel(u)`. If we are **not** validating within a controller, adding a referece to `System.Web.Mvc.Controller.TryValidateModel()` would be an unneded reference since we don't use a controller.

Answer (score 68):

I made an entry in the Stack Overflow Documentation explaining how to do this:

### Validation Context

Any validation needs a context to give some information about what is being validated. This can include various information such as the object to be validated, some properties, the name to display in the error message, etc.

```
ValidationContext vc = new ValidationContext(objectToValidate); // The simplest form of validation context. It contains only a reference to the object being validated.
```

Once the context is created, there are multiple ways of doing validation.

### Validate an Object and All of its Properties

```
ICollection<ValidationResult> results = new List<ValidationResult>(); // Will contain the results of the validation
bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(objectToValidate, vc, results, true); // Validates the object and its properties using the previously created context.
// The variable isValid will be true if everything is valid
// The results variable contains the results of the validation
```

### Validate a Property of an Object

```
ICollection<ValidationResult> results = new List<ValidationResult>(); // Will contain the results of the validation
bool isValid = Validator.TryValidatePropery(objectToValidate.PropertyToValidate, vc, results, true); // Validates the property using the previously created context.
// The variable isValid will be true if everything is valid
// The results variable contains the results of the validation
```

### And More

To learn more about manual validation see:

- [ValidationContext Class Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Validator Class Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Remember to specify `MemberName` on the validation context when validating a property, e.g. `vc.MemberName = nameof(objectToValidate.PropertyToValidate);`

Comment: `TryValidatePropery` seems like that is misspelled here and it only takes 3 parameters 
Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.tryvalidateproperty

Answer (score 11):

Since the question is asking specifically about ASP.NET MVC, you can use the [`TryValidateObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.tryvalidatemodel) inside your [`Controller`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller) action.

Your desired method overload is `TryValidateModel(Object)`

> Validates the specified model instance.
>
> Returns true if the model validation is successful; otherwise false.

Your modified source code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewUser(UserViewModel userVM)
{
    User u = new User();
    u.Name = null;

    if (this.TryValidateObject(u))
    {
        TempData["NewUserCreated"] = "New user created sucessfully";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Good, but what is the reason if `TryValidateObject` fails? I want to get more details about validation?

Answer (score 10):

I wrote a wrapper to make this a bit less clunky to work with.

Usage:

```
var response = SimpleValidator.Validate(model);

var isValid = response.IsValid;
var messages = response.Results;
```

Or if you only care about checking validity, it's even tighter:

```
var isValid = SimpleValidator.IsModelValid(model);
```

Complete source:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Ether.Validation
{
    public static class SimpleValidator
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Validate the model and return a response, which includes any validation messages and an IsValid bit.
        /// </summary>
        public static ValidationResponse Validate(object model)
        {
            var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
            var context = new ValidationContext(model);

            var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(model, context, results, true);
         
            return new ValidationResponse()
            {
                IsValid = isValid,
                Results = results
            };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Validate the model and return a bit indicating whether the model is valid or not.
        /// </summary>
        public static bool IsModelValid(object model)
        {
            var response = Validate(model);

            return response.IsValid;
        }
    }

    public class ValidationResponse
    {
        public List<ValidationResult> Results { get; set; }
        public bool IsValid { get; set; }

        public ValidationResponse()
        {
            Results = new List<ValidationResult>();
            IsValid = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Or at this gist: https://gist.github.com/kinetiq/faed1e3b2da4cca922896d1f7cdcc79b

Answer (score 0):

There is another approach to validation, which is more easy reusable - **FluentValidation**

This library allows to play with inheritance, different rule sets for one model and has many other cool features. [Read about advantages here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807472/fluent-validation-vs-data-annotations).

With this library definition of validation rules is separated from model and code will look next way:

```
public class UserValidator:AbstractValidator<User>
{
    public UserValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty();
    }
}
```

Usage will look next way:

```
var validator = new UserValidator();
var validationResult = await validator.ValidateAsync(model);
```

Comment: How is this more reusable? What if I had an `AdminUser` class with an `AdminName` property that should be non-empty - surely I'd have to create an `AdminUserValidator`, give it a constructor, and create the rule (i.e. no re-use, really). With the attribute approach, all I have to do is use the `RequiredAttribute` and stick it on any property I want (excellent re-use). (I'm not sure if NonEmpty here means "required and non-empty" or just "if it's present, it should not be empty". If the latter, an equivalent custom attribute can be created pretty effortlessly).