# Is there built-in ways to do configuration model bind validation without IOptions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I know use this can do

```cs
services.AddOptions<MyConfigModel>()
        .Bind(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(MyConfigModel)))
        .ValidateDataAnnotations();
```

But I don't like access by option.Value.xxx.

I prefer:

```cs
var myconfig = new MyConfigModel();
Configuration.Bind(nameof(MyConfigModel), myconfig);   

services.AddSingleton(myconfig);
```

Comment: You could just use [`TryValidateObject`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17138972/2630078) directly, but realise that the options pattern provides a number of benefits (e.g. auto-reload).

Comment: Does it watch the file changes ?

Comment: See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2#reload-configuration-data-with-ioptionssnapshot).

Comment: @KirkLarkin Does "Options Validation" validate recursively entire object graph ? Such as Class nested Class.

Comment: I don't *think* it does, but I *think* that's because `TryValidateObject` doesn't do it out of the box either. Honestly, I haven't tried it so I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For avoiding resolve `MyConfigModel` by `IOptions<MyConfigModel>.Value`, you could try register `MyConfigModel` like

```
services.AddOptions<MyConfigModel>()
    .Bind(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(MyConfigModel)))
    .ValidateDataAnnotations();
services.AddScoped(serviceProvider => serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MyConfigModel>>().Value);
```

And then use like

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{       
    private readonly MyConfigModel _myConfigModel2;
    public HomeController(MyConfigModel myConfigModel)
    {
        _myConfigModel2 = myConfigModel;
    }              
}
```