# Use ValidationMetadataProviderContext with the Validator object

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core-mvc

I have two worlds of validation mechanisms in my ASP.NET Core 3.1 application:

1. In `services.AddControllersWithViews` I add a custom `IValidationMetadataProvider` to `options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders`. It changes the `ErrorMessage` of the default `ValidationAttribute`s that are defined in my model classes to something that can be localised. This happens for all models that are validated through MVC model-binding. The results are in the usual place of `ModelState`.

   Here's some code for that:

   ```
   // In Startup.ConfigureServices:
   services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
   {
       options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new LocalizedValidationMetadataProvider());
   });

   internal class LocalizedValidationMetadataProvider : IValidationMetadataProvider
   {
       public void CreateValidationMetadata(ValidationMetadataProviderContext context)
       {
           foreach (object attribute in context.ValidationMetadata.ValidatorMetadata)
           {
               if (attribute is ValidationAttribute valAttr)
               {
                   if (valAttr is RequiredAttribute reqAttr)
                       reqAttr.ErrorMessage = "@input_required";
                   if (valAttr is MaxLengthAttribute maxLenAttr)
                       maxLenAttr.ErrorMessage = $"@max_length {maxLenAttr.Length}";
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. When reading and validating data from other sources (like importing from a JSON file), I use the [`Validator` object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45385021/143684) to validate the models using their standard `ValidationAttribute`s and other mechanisms (`IValidatableObject`). The results are in a local list of `ValidationResult`s.

   Here's what I've done so far:

   ```
   var vc = new ValidationContext(importedModel);
   var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
   bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(importedModel, vc, results, true);
   if (!isValid)
   {
       // Here I need results with the localisable messages like "@input_required"
       // Instead, I get the default "The (Name) field is required."
   }
   ```

Now the problem is that in the second case, the default messages for the `ValidationAttribute`s are generated and in the `ValidationResult`s I have no reference to the source of these messages. I need to integrate the first case somehow into the second scenario.

The `IValidationMetadataProvider` implementation works on validation metadata found in a `ValidationMetadataProviderContext` instance. I tried to trace down where that comes from and how MVC model-binding uses it but I am a bit lost in the [aspnetcore source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore) with all its interfaces.

How would I bring the `ValidationContext` of `Validator` together with the `ValidationMetadataProviderContext` of MVC?

**Edit:** Having read the relevant source code a bit further, I have the impression that it's not possible to use `Validator` like this. Alternatively, how could I use MVC's `ModelState`-related mechanisms for objects that did not come from a web form request but another arbitrary source? Can I tell one of MVC's classes to process an object as if it came from the request and through model binding?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have problem with deserialization?

Try add AddNewtonsoftJson:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
services.AddRazorPages().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Comment: No, there is no problem with deserialisation. I get the model object correctly. But its contents can still be invalid, like strings being empty that must not be empty, which is what the `ValidationAttribute`s in the model class should check. It's the messages that *they* produce that are the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be pretty easy once you dig through the ASP.NET Core source code. So `Validator` has no possibility to alter the `ValidationAttribute`s that are defined in the model classes. I can't use that for my purpose. But MVC's classes are suitable for that. In fact all established extensions are still there.

All I need is to fetch an `IObjectModelValidator` from dependency injection. It can validate an object. It requires some more objects that can simply be created. Here's the full solution:

```
IObjectModelValidator objectModelValidator;   // from DI

// In an MVC action method:
var actionContext = new ActionContext();
actionContext.HttpContext = HttpContext;
var validationStateDict = new ValidationStateDictionary();
objectModelValidator.Validate(actionContext, validationStateDict, "", model);
if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // The usual methods...
    // Can go through the ModelState errors and localise the placeholder messages there
}
```