# WPF field validation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Hi I'm new in C# and I have created a WPF form that takes in a csv and save it in the db. Now I was wondering if there are a `Validation Library` that I can use to make those field checking easier? Like I would like to implement a field required or something and it will throw an error if the field is not required. How can I achieve this? I have read some code that has something like this

```
[Required] // Not sure if this is the correct format
public string Name()
{
  get;set;
}
```

So basically I was thinking of a middleware type of validation where I just place the `[Required]` attribute in the model class and it will do the validation for me. Is there such a thing?

Update: What I mean by validating is that when after I select a csv file, it will read through per row/column now each column will be validated like ex. For `column[0]` (assuming this is field for Name) then when this field is read and assign to a variable it should be validated before proceeding in assigning to a variable. Not sure if this is possible more it's something like this

```
string[] content = row.Split('|');
Customer customer = new Customer(content);
Lis<KeyValuePair<string, string>> rowList = Converter.ToKeyValuePair(customer);
```

And here's the code for the `Customer` class

```
class Converter
{
    public static List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> ToKeyValuePair(Customer customer)
    {
         List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> rowList = new List<keyValuePari<string, string>>();
         rowList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>('name', customer.Name));
    }

    return rowList;
}
```

// Class Customer

```
class Customer
{
    private string _name;

    public Customer(string[] content)
    {
        this.Name = content[0];
    }

    [Required] // Maybe some auto validation here where when the property is accessed it should be validated immediately
    public string Name
    {
         get { return _name; }
         set {
             // I'm thinking of some validation here?
              _name = value;
         }
    }
}
```

As you can see in my example I wanted that whenever the property like `this.Name = content[0]` is accessed it automatically validate if the content has value or not

Comment: Do you mean validating the model in the  WPF form? Like disabling a 'Save' or 'Submit' button until the input is valid?

Comment: @IvanVargas will update my question

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138749/how-to-manually-validate-a-model-with-attributes) might help you

Comment: @IvanVargas, That is for web(asp.net). WPF is desktop platform.

Comment: @MadzQuestioning, In wpf, you should use [IDataErrorInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-validation-logic-on-custom-objects) interface on your model/viewmodel instead of attributes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in "validation library" as such. You should implement the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface in your class:

```
public class Model
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter a username.")]
    [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 4,
        ErrorMessage = "The username must be between 4 and 10 characters long")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "The username must only contain letters (a-z, A-Z).")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter a name.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, ICollection<string>>
       _validationErrors = new Dictionary<string, ICollection<string>>();
    private readonly Model _user = new Model();

    public string Username
    {
        get { return _user.Username; }
        set
        {
            _user.Username = value;
            ValidateModelProperty(value, "Username");
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _user.Name; }
        set
        {
            _user.Name = value;
            ValidateModelProperty(value, "Name");
        }
    }

    protected void ValidateModelProperty(object value, string propertyName)
    {
        if (_validationErrors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
            _validationErrors.Remove(propertyName);

        ICollection<ValidationResult> validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
        ValidationContext validationContext =
            new ValidationContext(_user, null, null) { MemberName = propertyName };
        if (!Validator.TryValidateProperty(value, validationContext, validationResults))
        {
            _validationErrors.Add(propertyName, new List<string>());
            foreach (ValidationResult validationResult in validationResults)
            {
                _validationErrors[propertyName].Add(validationResult.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
        RaiseErrorsChanged(propertyName);
    }
    ...
}
```

The full data validation procedure in WPF, including examples of how to implement this interface and validate data using data annotations, is described in [this blog post](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/). Please read it through and feel free to ask another question if you run into a more specific issue.

Comment: Thanks for this.. will try this one.. Will accept when it works thanks