# Using Data Annotations (specifically DataType) in a console app

Tags: c#, validation, console-application, data-annotations

I'm trying to validate an email data type in a console app using Data Annotations, but it is returning "true" even though I know for a fact the email address isn't valid (I'm sending in "notavalidemail").

Here is my code.

Model:

```
class Email
    {
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string email { get; set; }
    }
```

Snippet from Program.cs:

```
     Email emailAdress = new Email();
     emailAdress.email = "notavalidemail";
     var vc = new ValidationContext(emailAdress, null, null);
     var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(emailAdress, vc, null);
```

Am I missing something, or is it even possible to validate data types this way in a console app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DataType` attributes are used primarily for formatting and not validation, So 
you have to use `[EmailAddress]` instead of `[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]`:

```
public class Email
{
    [EmailAddress]
    public string email { get; set; }
}
```

Now if you run your application you'll get this validation error:

```
The email field is not a valid e-mail address.
```

**One more thing**: If you need validation for all properties, you have to pass in `true` for the last parameter of `TryValidateObject` method:

```
var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(email, context, results, true);
```

> true to validate all properties; if false, only required attributes
>   are validated..

Comment: I thought I had tried this way as well, but I just changed my code to this and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use fluent validation instead. Its an easy to use library where u can validate a model and check if the values provided were correct with validate method.

Check the link below:

https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/

The example below may some what help you with this!

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/326647/FluentValidation-and-Unity

Check this answer too

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6807706/2191018

Comment: Does FluentValidation also support annotation based validations too? Instead of RuleSet and following expressions?